# Crosstab Non-Numeric "Boolean Data"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I don't know how to call my desired output, but I need to achieve following result inside MS Access (Jet DB):

My Data:
[image]

My desired Result:
[image]

Can this be achieved in a crosstab query? The fact, that there is no numeric data makes it hard for me to understand what should be the Column Heading, Row Heading, and what should be the Value or grouped.

I hope you can help me with this issue. Explanations rather than solutions are welcome.
Of course these are example data. I will transfer it to my real problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you think a CROSSTAB is needed - your raw table is already non-normalized. Looks like you just need to do an aggregate query using Max() function if you really have a letter `x` in fields. BTW, `desinfection` is a misspelling of `disinfection`.

Comment: Why select Excel tag?